# aliases working in terminal but not in iterm

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, alias

i use iterm and ohmyzsh.

this is what i have in **my ~/.zshrc** (after all the other stuff)

```
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias phart1="php artisan"
alias pp1="phyton3"
alias asd1="echo we are having fun"
alias c1="clear"
```

this is what i have in my **~/.bash_profile**

```
alias phart2="php artisan"
alias pp2="python3"
alias asd2="echo we are having lots of fun"
alias c2="clear"
```

inside the app **terminal**
the aliases with 1 works, the one with 2 don't

inside the app **iTerm**
no alias work

in both cases *the error is zsh:command not found*

what is it wrong?
looks like terminal see just zshrc while iterm ignore everything
how to fix?
thanks

Comment: How exactly don't they work. In general an alias is a simple text replacement of what you type with the value of the alias.

Comment: command not found... it's like is not taking my aliases

Comment: You have at least one spelling error in your .zshrc. What is your default shell - what is the command staring in Terminal and iTerm - comparre the same shell in both not different ones

Comment: i used source ~/.zshrc to update the shell and now the commands in .zshrc works!

Comment: pp1 won't work - and why are you showing use ~/.bashrc - please answer the questions above

Comment: you are right, sorry! used bashrc to test... how to fix pp1 instead? aside the typo... how can i allow it to receive an argument after it?  for instance how can i specify that ee should echo me whatever i write after ee?

Comment: @rita1989 Neither Terminal.app nor iTerm care at all about your shell configuration files.  Whichever shell you are using cares about your shell configuration files.  As documented, `zsh` parses ~/.zshrc for interactive login shells, so presumably Terminal.app is starting `zsh` as a login shell, while iTerm is not.

Comment: I would first separate the two issues: .zshrc is only relevant for zsh, and .bash_profile, as the name suggests, is only relevant for bash. If you are running bash, you certainly do **not** get an error message _**zsh**:command not found_. If you are only running zsh, I don't know why you mention .bash_profile at all. In addition, the behaviour depends on how you have configured your Terminal. If you configured iTerm and Terminal.app differently, it would be no surprise if the startup of a shell behaves differently.